# Several Errors when trying to enter data into mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I keep getting this error when trying to use my form to submit data into mysql

"Insertion Failed:Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"

```
<?php

include 'dbc.php';


$rank = $_POST['rank'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$platoon = $_POST['platoon'];
$squad = $_POST['squad'];
$justsuta =$_POST['justsuta'];
$fdate =$_POST['fdate'];
$tdate =$_POST['tdate'];
$ddate1 =$_POST['ddate1'];
$ddate2 =$_POST['ddate2'];
$ddate3 =$_POST['ddate3'];
$sdate1 =$_POST['sdate1'];
$sdate2 =$_POST['sdate2'];
$sdate3 =$_POST['sdate3'];



$sql_insert = "INSERT into `forms`
       (`rank`,`lname`,`fname`,`platoon`,`squad`,`justsuta`,`fdate`,`tdate`,`ddate1`,`ddate2`,`ddate3`,`sdate1`,`sdate2`,`sdate3`)
       VALUES('$rank','$lname','$fname','$platoon','$squad','$justsuta','$fdate','$tdate','$ddate1','$ddate2','$ddate3','$sdate1','$sdate2','$sdate3', NOW())";

mysql_query($sql_insert) or die("Insertion Failed:" . mysql_error());

?>
```

Do i have something wrong with my code? Thank you for your help in advance

Comment: Edit your question and show the value of `$sql_insert` after you insert the variables.  About 95% of the time, the problem is obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that you've supplied more data than the amount of columns you've specified.

You specify `14` columns:

```
(`rank`,`lname`,`fname`,`platoon`,`squad`,`justsuta`,`fdate`,`tdate`,`ddate1`,`ddate2`,`ddate3`,`sdate1`,`sdate2`,`sdate3`)
```

Yet you supply `15`

```
VALUES('$rank','$lname','$fname','$platoon','$squad','$justsuta','$fdate','$tdate','$ddate1','$ddate2','$ddate3','$sdate1','$sdate2','$sdate3', NOW())";
```

You either have to remove the `NOW()` or the `$sdate3` in the data you supply.